# How Can "uri" be Empty?

Tags: metadata, fungible-token

I am helping apply metadata updates to a token called aBion. You can see it here:

Solscan: https://solscan.io/token/J3ts1ZEyQeUAbUyYHjZR6sE93YQTrfBzho8UKWnEa1j#metadata

Solana Explorer: https://explorer.solana.com/address/J3ts1ZEyQeUAbUyYHjZR6sE93YQTrfBzho8UKWnEa1j/metadata

Its icon, website, and other information traditionally stored in metadata is all present. However, you can see that the "uri" field in its on-chain metadata is blank!

How is that possible? I was planning on uploading the new metadata JSON to Arweave, and then assigning the on-chain "uri" value to this new URI. But the empty "uri" field in the current token makes me concerned that I am missing something, or that something could break if I used this method.

I appreciate your insight on this a lot. I really need to know if updating the "uri" value would cause irreversible problems. And, if it would, what the correct way to update the token metadata (e.g. its associated icon) is in this case.